# Accept CTRL + A keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

```
    $('.numberOnly').bind('keypress', function(event){
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");
        validation(event, regex);
    });
```

This is my validation code for an input to only accept numbers. But this validation causes <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to not working. 
How can I configure this code for it to accept <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ?

Comment: Have you looked into `type="number"`?

Comment: Some browsers support `type="tel"`... Just giving you options.

Answer (score 0):

Check the keycode that is happening.

```
$('.numberOnly').bind('keypress',function(event){
    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) { 
        console.log('this is 0-9 or numpad 0-9');
    }
});
```